# Why Linq Except() with custom Equals IEquatable return items when he shouln't

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
   public static void Main()
   {
       List<Holiday> holidayDifference = new List<Holiday>();

       List<Holiday> remoteHolidays = new List<Holiday>
       {
           new Holiday { Name = "Xmas", hello ="aproperty" },
           new Holiday { Name = "Hanukkah", hello ="hello" },
           new Holiday { Name = "Ramadan" }
       };

       List<Holiday> localHolidays = new List<Holiday>
       {
           new Holiday { Name = "Xmas", hello="different" },
           new Holiday { Name = "Ramadan", hello="hello" }
       };

       holidayDifference = remoteHolidays
           .Except(localHolidays)
           .ToList();

       holidayDifference.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Name));
   }
}

class Holiday : IEquatable<Holiday>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string hello { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Holiday other)
    {

        return Name == other.Name && hello != other.hello;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as Holiday);

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (Name, hello).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I implement a custom Equals with Iquatable on the Holiday class. The condition i want to apply is "consider" object A with compared B equals when the Name is equal and the hello property is not equal.

Technically the result should be

```
Hanukkah
Ramadan
```

Because Xmas has the hello property different from the compared list.

But I get

```
Xmas 
Hanukkah
Ramadan
```

What am i doing wrong

Comment: `return Name == other.Name && hello != other.hello;` - wait, can you clarify that? that means that something doesn't equal *itself* which is... a dangerous start

Comment: it equals itself since the property Name is equal to the Name of the compared object but if the hello property of the other object also equals i want to consider the objects not equal

Comment: This is just an example of a bigger picture. I understand that it doesn't make sense. I would like to understand why the results are not like expected. Maybe the Except Linq is not correctly implemented. return Name == other.Name && hello != other.hello should return true for the first compared object (Xmas) because the condition is met, so according to Except Linq the Xmas should be excluded from the result list. Why it doesn't happen.

Comment: @ClaudioFerraro No, an object never equals itself using that definition, which is a problem. What's the purpose of this equality definition?

Comment: The purpose is not relevant in my case I need to exclude items where the hello property are different and with same name property

Comment: If you write code where the operators do not follow the rules of those operators, bad things happen. You are *required* to write an implementation of equality where (1) things are always equal to themselves, (2) A == B and B == A are always the same, and (3) if A == B and B == C are both true then A == C must also be true. **If you violate these rules, bad things can happen**.  You've violated the rules. Bad things are happening. This is right and proper; don't violate the rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations are inconsistent. Take these two objects:

```
A: Name="John",  hello="Hola"
B: Name="John",  hello="Aloha"
```

These objects are "equal" but give different hash codes. Since getting the hash code is the first step of determining "equality" in many processes, this will give you inconsistent results.

But more importantly, your definition of "equal" is problematic. Using your definition, an object will never equal itself, which will cause problems in sorting and hashing algorithms.  It is also not transitive. Take a third object:

```
C: Name="John",  hello="Hola"
```

Now `A` and `B` are "equal", and `B` and `C` are "equal", but `A` and `C` are NOT equal. That, too, is going to cause problems.

> I need to exclude items where the hello property are different and with same name property

So forget defining an "equals" method and just use `!Any`:

```
   holidayDifference = remoteHolidays
       .Where(rh => !localHolidays.Any(lh => 
                                  lh.Name == rh.Name && 
                                  lh.hello != rh.hello))
       .ToList();
```

Comment: ok. and how should I fix the GetHashCode in order to make it work?

Comment: @ClaudioFerraro The problem is your "equals" definition, not your hash code. There are at least two problems with your definition - it is not reflexive and not transitive.

Comment: Technically, changing the hash code to only look at the Name should make the code work as desired, since the Equals function is called when there is a match on the HashCode. Right now, the Equals function is not being called since the HashCodes don't match. 

That said, whether doing so is advisable is a different story.

Comment: @Kei True, but the equals definition is still invalid.

Comment: @Kei: D Stanley is correct: there are *rules* for how `Equals` and `GetHashCode` are *required* to be implemented and if you break those rules, bad things happen. A good summary of the rules can be found here: https://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/

Comment: Eric Lippert's guidelines are focused on how to define a valid implementation for GetHashCode.  I suggest also reading [MSDN How to: define value equality for a type (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type).  That said, D Stanley already covered what is wrong with implementation of Equality: It is neither reflexive nor transitive.